# How to create a node in Drupal 7 with a custom nid

Tags: nodes

I have to create a node in drupal 7 with a custom nid but the solution I've tried doesn't works (The created node not appears in the backend). 
If I create the same node without the custom nid, it works.

Code:

```
$node = new stdClass();

$node->nid = intval($insert['id']);
$node->vid = intval($insert['id']);
$node->uid = 1;
$node->type = 'nodetype';

$node->title = $insert['name'];
$node->created = time();
$node->changed = $node->created;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->format = 2;
$node->status = 1;
$node->language = 'en';

$node->field_custom_1 = array('und' => array(array( 'value' => $insert['foo'] )));
$node->field_custom_2 = array('und' => array(array('value' => $insert['hello'])));
$node->field_custom_3 = array('und' => array(array('value' => $insert['world']))); 

if ($node = node_submit($node)) {
    node_save($node);       
    drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$node->title." : ".$node->nid." added correctly"));
}
else { 
    drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$node->title." added incorrectly"), "error");
}
```

What's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7

I believe node_save() takes all the node edit form input and builds a new node with a `node->id` for you.

`node_save()` either tries to update an existing node, or give you a newly saved one. You want to set what NID it gives you back.

Assuming an SQL storage engine for Nodes. You'd have to pick a NID greater than the current SQL `MAX(id) FROM {node}` ...

You could then make a new node entity with `entity_create`( [See Creating and Editing Entities Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1377614) ) just passing the bare parameters you want: NID, type, bundle.

Then you could do a `node_load()` and then a `node_save()` with your code above to actually build out the rest of the node ...

That's what I would try.

Comment: It's a shame the user will never see this answer: He deleted his account right after asking the question. `:|`

Comment: and I was just about to add you might be able to fake it with `$node->is_new=TRUE;`, too :)